# escaping sybase query with hexadecimal of single qoute

Tags: php, escaping, hex, sql-injection, sybase

I am working with a Sybase database (not of my creating) and PHP, and I see that all single quotes in the database are stored as hexadecimal representation of single quote "\x16". I don't believe this is very common because I'm only finding information saying to escape single quote with another single quote for Sybase. Escaping with Single quote is not working for this database but replacing ' with \x16 is.
My question is if it is sufficient enough to do:

```
str_replace( "'", "\x16", $search );
```

It works, but is it safe to replace all incoming single quotes with \x16?

Will that protect against injection?

Should it be the same for INSERT, UPDATE etc. ?

In sybase, are there any other characters that I need to worry about? (I do see double quotes and slashes stored as literals (I believe the word is) )

What do you think about this storage of single quotes in general?